# macOS: Select last used window when switching to an app

Tags: macos

I am running Google Chrome with multiple open windows on different desktops. Mission Control is set so that monitors have separate Spaces.

When using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to Chrome from another app, the automatically selected Chrome window is not always the last one that had focus. Sometimes it selects a Chrome window on a different desktop.

Is there any way to ensure the window getting focus is the last window that had focus when using Chrome prior to switching away from it?

I have had this problem through multiple versions of macOS.